# PrestaShop says the voucher is already used, but it isn't

Tags: prestashop

As per subject, I'm facing issues with a voucher: when entering it for an order (both from front-end and back-end) PrestaShop 1.6 says the "voucher is already used" but it isn't.

I also inspected the MySQL DB via phpMyAdmin, I looked table ps_orders_cart_rule and that voucher is not used in any order.

Other vouchers works fine.

Comment: What kind of voucher are you talking about? Was it from loyalty module?

Comment: Is the problem connected with expiration date? I've found similar problem like new voucher period time is 2013-2014(it's already outdated even it's brand new). Are we talking about the same problem?

Comment: No I checked date and availability. After some days Problem solved without any intervention. It seems to happen in random way